# I might change three times - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> When I am in my first phase, I am as dark as the space.
>   When I am in my
>   second phase, I am as red as the sun.
>   When I am in my third phase, I
>   am becoming old and disappear into nothingness.

**What am I?**

Comment: "As space" or "as the space"? Is this on purpose?

Comment: well, I mean outer space.

Comment: Ok, just checking.

Comment: You forgot the fourth one, so my answer wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think its-

> **COAL/CHARCOAL**

When I am in my first phase, I am as dark as the space.
When I am in my second phase, I am as red as the sun.
When I am in my third phase, I am becoming old and disappear into nothingness.

> Coal is dark like a space. When burnt it turns red as sun. And then it turns into ashes.

Comment: Woahh.. awesome. Yes you're right. The phases describe the color of the answer, which is coal/charcoal.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be simply

> a star?

*When I am in first phase, I am as dark as the space.*

> Before the star is properly formed, it's literally just empty space with dust scattered through it.

*When I am in my second phase, I am as red as the sun.*

> Many stars are red.

*When I am in my third place, I am becoming old and disappear into nothingness.*

> Finally the star, now ancient, fades away into nothing, perhaps after a supernova.

Comment: Nope. All the phases describe the `*censored here :)*` of the answer.